# Respect Filter Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a table, and three different (Open, Close, Pending) , when the user filter by client, see the corresponding values.

But when the user changes from example: Open to Close the table lost the filter, there is a way to respect the filter between gsp views?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the value= on the g:select (see below code) and the page should remember the setting.

```
    <div class="form-group ${hasErrors(bean: searchCommand, field: 'testTypeId', 'has-error')}">
        <label for="testType">
            Test Type
        </label>
        <g:select id="testType" name="testTypeId" from="${TestType.findAllByActive(true).sort({it.sortOrder})}" optionKey="id"
                  value="${searchCommand?.testTypeId}" noSelection="['':'-Choose One-']" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
```